# Other nosql database than mongodb with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-plugins, nosql

I would like to use another platform than mongodb with mongoose.

I used mongoose in my school project, and my school ask me to have a multiple database project.

Any idea ? I don't want to duplicate my code..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is MongoDB-specific as the website says:

> elegant mongodb object modeling for node.js

so it's not possible to use it with another NoSQL tool.

Answer (score 0):

[CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-mongoose) from Azure is compatible with Mongoose and I have used this setup.

[TingoDB](http://www.tingodb.com/) claims to be compatible too using [an additional driver called Tingus](https://github.com/sergeyksv/tungus).

[NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) claims "its API is a subset of the MongoDB API" so there may be some compatibility with Mongoose too.

There may be other projects out there.